# How to use generic type with extends to pass parameters into more specific typed function

Tags: typescript

I wrote this [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLVgC4oDOwATgJYB2A5gNzoC+66okUAQgIbHKEkWVQAfNJmwATdsAj4AIhIi1sUADaki+ImSq0G6AGYBXcgGNgpOORwQiAHgAqUCAA9J5UQTadBsBAD4AFKSSALYE+LYA2gC6AJTCikbmBHBKEAB0SnCUAcEE0QrYkkQATNkQIXn0jAbGpuaWxaUh+BzEUV7wcFGxGPGJyWkZWYFludpAA) and I can't understand why it isn't possible to do this.

Here's the code as well:

```
type Foo = {
    t: string;
}

type Bar = string | {
    date: Date;
    list: string;
}

function test<T extends Bar | Foo>(items: T[]) {
    console.log(items);
    test2(items);
}

function test2(items: Bar[] | Foo[]) {
    console.log(items);
}
```

The error I get is when calling `test2` in `test` saying that `T[]` isn't a valid type for the type of `test2`.

Why's that?

Comment: I'm currently composing an answer and demonstrative example for this... give me just a few minutes.

Comment: the reason is `items` can be `[Bar, Foo]`, but `test2` needs `[Bar, Bar]` or `[Foo, Foo]`. The simplest solution is to change `test` to `test<T extends Bar[] | Foo[]>(items: T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the compiler error for the code you've shown:

```ts
function test <T extends Bar | Foo>(items: T[]): void {
  console.log(items);
  test2(items);
  //    ~~~~~
}
```

```
Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bar[] | Foo[]'.
  Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'Bar[]'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
      Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
        Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ date: Date; list: string; }'.
            Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type '{ date: Date; list: string; }'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ date: Date; list: string; }'. (2345)
```

What this means is that — currently — your `test` function has a signature that expects an array of values. Each individual value can be of a type that is assignable to **either** `Foo` **or** `Bar`: it's acceptable to provide an array value with mixed elements of `Foo` **and** `Bar`. For example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKwBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQNokUAQgIb7K4EnkA+aNUKABMWwCNgAioiLUEAbQnmx4iZWtToAzAK7EAxsEJxiGCHigAeACpQIADzHEhOZmyh94cAHwAKQmIBbHGwrAG0AXQBKbAA3OEIhfkE9Yxw4OQgAOjk4Uj9AnEjZKAB6EtM8ACZ8iCCimgo6FOJzNnwWEA5QgTQMbAByAAsIORz+ygAaHv6Adzh8OSF+qcF0ETFsYggZqCkxH0iJqAUlKH6VcYop8Np6M2AfNo6i0vK4AGsaIA)

```ts
const array = [
  { t: 'hello' },
  'world',
  { date: new Date(), list: 'str' },
];

test(array); // ok
```

However, your `test2` function has a signature which expects an array argument of either **exclusively** `Foo` elements or **exclusively** `Bar` elements:

```ts
function test2 (items: Bar[] | Foo[]): void;
```

So, when providing the same array to `test2`, the error occurs:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKwBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQNokUAQgIb7K4EnkA+aNUKABMWwCNgAioiLUEAbQnmx4iZWtToAzAK7EAxsEJxiGCHgBMUABSExAWxzZW+ANoBdKH3hx3ASn6CesY4cHIQAHRycKQ29ji+6nRBxHhQbPgsIBwuAmgY2ADkABYQclEFlAA0uQUA7nD4ckIF1YLoImLYxBC1UFJiVr6VUApKUAUqFRTVbrT0ZsDmVumZCTQA9OuCggB+e3sbWwCCUABuEPhZOIR2hHJsUEF2YHcXUBf4DVBFLGCQKd8LhAgA)

```ts
const array = [
  { t: 'hello' },
  'world',
  { date: new Date(), list: 'str' },
];

test2(array);
//    ~~~~~
// A very similar compiler error happens here
```

You can mitigate the error by modifying the parameter of the `test2` function to accept an array of mixed `Foo` and `Bar` elements, like this:

```ts
(Bar | Foo)[]
```

which, when put all together, would look like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKwBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQNokUAQgIb7K4EnkA+aNUKABMWwCNgAioiLUEAbQnmx4iZWtToAzAK7EAxsEJxiGCHigAeACpQIADzHEhOZmyh94cAHwAKQmIBbHGwrAG0AXQBKbAA3OEIhfkE9Yxw4OQgAOjk4Uj9AnEjZUzwAJnyIIKKoAHoaqDgAaxoKOjqoHX1DYxLgUqgKoOxWfAj3WAQIyP5OgyMTMTKB-0rggZHxz0ip2PjE1AEoFOI0jOzcwcL1GiA)

```ts
type Foo = { t: string };

type Bar = string | {
  date: Date;
  list: string;
};

function test <T extends Bar | Foo>(items: T[]): void {
  console.log(items);
  test2(items); // ok
}

// function test2 (items: Bar[] | Foo[]) {
function test2 (items: (Bar | Foo)[]): void {
  console.log(items);
}
```

Alternatively, if your intention was to have a more strict `test` function that accepts a generic array of exclusively `Foo` elements **or** exclusively `Bar` elements, you can rewrite it like this and achieve the same compatibility with your existing `test2` function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKwBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQNokUAQgIb7K4EnkA+aNUKABMWwCNgAioiLUEAbQnmx4iZWtToAzAK7EAxsEJxiGCHigAeACpQIADzHEhOZmwDaAXSh94cTwD4ACkIxAFscbCsASmwANzhCIX5BPWMcODkIADo5OFJgsJwo2VM8ACYCiHDiqAB6Wqg4AGsaCi1dAyMTMXKoSvDsVnxPb1gETyjkqFTidMycvP6i9RogA)

```ts
function test <T extends Bar[] | Foo[]>(items: T): void {
  console.log(items);
  test2(items); // ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! If possible, do you think you can add @Antoniossss two types solution as well? Or is it better to be separate?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688092/how-to-use-generic-type-with-extends-to-pass-parameters-into-more-specific-typed/74688311?noredirect=1#comment131824263_74688311) @LoyalPotato It has no effect in [a structural type system like TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html): in my personal opinion, it is just noise to alias the generics separately. See evidence in the playground: Code in this answer: https://tsplay.dev/wRzlXw, Code in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688201/438273): https://tsplay.dev/NV7k7m

Comment: Yeah I see your point

Answer (score 1):

If you change `test2` to following signature, it will be acceptable

`function test2(items: Array<Bar|Foo>)`

Its because

`test<T extends Bar | Foo> (items: T[])`

says that items is an array can be of both types A and B in the same time, (and your intention is probably to have either array of A or array of B), and `test2` requires unified array of one or the other type.

This would work as well

```
function test<A extends Bar, B extends Foo> (items: A[] | B[]) {
    console.log(items);
    test2(items);
}

function test2(items: Foo[] | Bar[]) {
    console.log(items);
}
```